# How to get beamer's bullet?

Tags: beamer, symbols

**Edit:** I'd like to get hold of the bullet character that *beamer* uses.  One use of it is as follows.

I'd like the left edges of the bullets of `itemize` to align with the left edge of the surrounding text.  My current strategy is to use the *calc* package to set `leftmargini`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
  \settowidth{\leftmargini}{$\blacktriangleright$}
  Text text text text text text text text text
  text text text text text text text text
  \begin{itemize}
    \item first
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which doesn't quite work (the indent width isn't quite right), perhaps because I'm using the wrong bullet.

How can you get hold of the exact bullet the beamer uses:

```
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\beamerbulleti} % 1st level
```

?

Regards,

Ryo

**Edit:** My reason for wanting to get hold of the bullet character is: It took me quite bit of time to be able to *guess* that `$\blacktriangleright$` is perhaps the right symbol.  What if you switch to another theme?  Each time you would have to dig into the style files to find it out.

I also sometimes want to use the same bullet outside the `itemize` environment: `text text text \textcolor{beamerbulletcolor}{\beamerbulleti} text text\ldots` and I want the bullet to change if/when I switch the theme.

Comment: I think the title of the question is misleading

Comment: Perhaps. I actually have other reasons for wanting to get the bullet symbol, so I should either add more material to my question so that the title becomes more suitable or change the title.

Comment: Currently your question is only about the indentation of the symbol, not about the real bullet symbol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol used for the first level itemize in beamer can be obtained with `\usebeamertemplate***{itemize item}`.

Comment: Much belated thanks!  That works in most cases.  I've just found it doesn't work with `raggedright`---`ERROR: You can't use `\raise' in internal vertical mode. . . . \beamer@@tmpl@itemize item ->\scriptsize \raise 1.25pt\hbox . . . `.